# Spring Boot Data Embedded Cassandra

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, embedded-cassandra

In my Spring Boot 1.5.1 application I'm going to write unit/integration tests for Cassandra related logic.

I have added folowing Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The default Spring Boot Cassandra configuration is going to connect with a real Cassandra DB server.

Is there any options in Spring/Spring Boot in order to configure my tests to use embedded Cassandra server ? If so, could you please show the required configuration.

Comment: here a tutorial explaining how to test with an embedded cassandra : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-tutorial

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We use on the project Cassandra + Spring Boot.
Here are the steps which worked for us:

a) Configure you test like this

```
import org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraDataSet;
import org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener;
import org.cassandraunit.spring.EmbeddedCassandra;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {
    CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
    ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class
})
@EmbeddedCassandra(timeout = 60000)
@CassandraDataSet(value = {"bootstrap_test.cql"}, keyspace = "local_test")
public abstract class BaseTest {
```

b) in your src/test/resources/application.properties, add this (please note, embedded cassandra starts on port 9142, but not on default 9042)

```
spring.data.cassandra.port=9142
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=local_test
```

c) Create empty file bootstrap_test.cql in src/test/resources

d) Add to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${cassandra-unit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${cassandra-unit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

This should be enough to run your tests with Embedded Cassandra. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Which is your data set here? I'm getting an error:

12:28:49.883 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1ebea008] to prepare test instance [net.gueka.user.service.UserServiceTest@38e7ed69]
org.cassandraunit.dataset.ParseException: Dataset not found

Comment: Why we need two dependencies with same artifactId and different scopes?

Answer (score 3):

There is no embedded Apache Cassandra support in Spring Boot available and it's not planned. There's little demand for embedded Apache Cassandra on the one hand, on the other hand, Apache Cassandra comes with a lot of dependencies that conflict with Boot's other dependencies.

Take a look at [Cassandra Unit](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit).

You can also build an own test rule when using JUnit tests that gives you full control over the Apache Cassandra version, runtime behavior and so on. Take a look at a possible implementation: [CassandraRule.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/29ecc65532d2445100967902dbb6551093f00148/spring-cql/src/test/java/org/springframework/cassandra/test/integration/CassandraRule.java#L56).

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old topic **BUT** there are two approaches to use embedded Cassandra with Spring.

### 1. First approach is with Cassandra Unit Spring

I have created a sample application and you can check out the following [Github](https://github.com/RazvanSebastian/EmbeddedCassandraServer_CassandraUnit) repository.

***Note***: the Embedded server start on the **9142** port NOT on the 9042 port !!!

### 2. Second approach is with ***maven-plugin***

**Step 1:**

Add the following maven plugins to **pom.xml**

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <startNativeTransport>true</startNativeTransport>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**Step 2:**

Create **cassandra/cql** directory at the root level of your project.
From this directory the Embedded Cassandra server will initialize your database.

**Important:** All files from this directory are **.cql** files.

*Example: cassandra/cql/load.cql*

**Step 3:**

Create integration tests.

**Important:** Only the test classes with **IT** suffix are interpreted by **surfire** plugin as integration tests.

**Step 4:**

***mvn verify*** to run the integration tests

Answer (score 1):

The solution by OP is no longer applicable to latest versions of Spring Boot, since `CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener` comes from [cassandra-unit-spring](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/tree/master/cassandra-unit-spring) that only works with JUnit 4, and the world has moved onto JUnit 5.

I've created a [cassandra-unit-spring](https://github.com/asarkar/cassandra-unit-spring) library that starts the Cassandra server and makes the ports available as Spring Boot environment properties.